# How to achieve conditional formatting of names between pages?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet with one page for team leaders to list their desired team members (first names, last names, emails) by row--each TL fills in one row--, and a second page where team members are listed who have actually registered with my program.

**Page 1**

```
+------------------------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
| Team Leader First Name | First Name | Email Address | First Name |   Email Address    |
+------------------------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
| Danielle               | Elizabeth  | XXX@tamu.edu  | Matthew    | XXX@tamu.edu       |
| Stoian                 | William    | XXX@tamu.edu  | Victoria   | XXX@email.tamu.edu |
| Christa                | Olivia     | XXX@tamu.edu  |            |                    |
+------------------------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
```

**Page 2**

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+
| Scholar First Name | Scholar Preferred Email |
+--------------------+-------------------------+
| elizabeth          | xxx@gmail.com           |
| william            | xxx@tamu.edu            |
+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to be able to see at a glance which of the names listed by the TL on pg 1 have not registered and thus don't appear on pg 2.

In the example above, I want Olivia, Matthew, and Victoria's names to appear red because she does not show up on pg2 (which means they still need to register). Everyone else should appear normally.

I tried at first to importrange from pg1 to get a clean list of the team members, then conditional formatting to match against pg2, the idea I had being it shows up red if a name is not found.

Comment: there are actually more unique identifiers for each person, but I left those out for anonymity, so there is no risk of multiple cells

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Import range from page 2 to page 1 the scholar first name to F12:F14

Conditional Formatting: Apply to range B2:B999(first name list in page 1)

```
  =NOT(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(B2),$F$12:$F$13,0)),ISBLANK(B2)))
```

Conditional Formatting2: Apply to range D2:D999(Second First name list)

```
 =NOT(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(D2),$F$12:$F$13,0)),ISBLANK(D2)))
```

Note: Instead of importing, You could also reference the second sheet using `INDIRECT`.

Comment: If this solved your problem, Mark this as solution by clicking ✔✓✅ on the left of this post.

Comment: @pnuts, Why not? All OP has to do is simply change B2 or D2 to the unique identifier list column without changing any of the rest.  Even without all that, I could simply use the email column (which is  obviously unique to each candidate) to match and still strike out only the name and not the email address. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @pnuts, `MATCH`,`VLOOKUP`and others  are NOT case sensitive. They're Case insensitive.

Comment: The answer helped, but it's not 100%. Cells are formatted despite their match on the list. I imported everything to a clean sheet so as not to disrupt my master list, but still can't seem to identify to issue even after taking apart the formula to educate myself. I appreciate the help. I can't post anything more from the data for anonymity reasons.

Comment: Check the individual match... Whether match (entry, list, 0) returns a number.

Comment: The main reason would be extra spaces. Try TRIM(A:A) . Then copy and paste values over the originals